# Difference between Capistrano and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, deployment, continuous-integration, capistrano, devops

I can deploy JAVA web applications using both Jenkins and Capistrano. If my CI tool is Jenkins which has plug ins for remote deployments, why should I use Capistrano for deployment? I want to know about pros and cons of both Jenkins and Capistrano.

Answer (score 4):

Capistrano gives you ability to deploy to servers outside of your CI system. CI/CD best practices recommends deploying build that has passed tests so adding a step to deploy green build is good practice.

Having said that there are times when you might need to do some ad hoc deployments, this is where tool like Capistrano helps.

I would suggest configure Jenkins to run cap commands for deployment instead of using jenkins plugins. This would give you ability to run deploy from both command line and CI.